# Is it possible that UICollectionViewCell gradient background layer render issue happens in case of rotation?

Tags: ios, rotation, uicollectionviewcell, gradient

So I have a custom **UICollectionViewController**, which contains simple rectangle cells (**UICollectionViewCell**). I would like to customize these with rounded corners and gradient background color. I could achieve this by setting the proper parameters for cells in the viewcontroller.

However, in case of rotation, my cells "collapse" just like there is something wrong with the rendering. Do you think I am missing something, or should I do this in a completely different way?

### Code

```swift
override func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        guard let cell = self.collectionView
            .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.reuseIdentifier,
                                 for: indexPath) as? AllCollectionViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of AllCollectionViewCell.")
        }
    
        // Configure the cell
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor,
                                UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor]
        
        gradientLayer.frame = cell.bounds

        cell.backgroundView = UIView()
        cell.backgroundView?.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        
        return cell
    }
```

The problem is not absolutely predictable, but it happens very often after **rotation** (going back to portrait after landscape view) and **scrolling**.

### Expected

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC7Qm.png

### Problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8VdX.png

Comment: set background color and corner radius in your custom cell class `AllCollectionViewCell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to set the properties in the cell class itself (AllCollectionViewCell) as suggested by [canister_exister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4311935/canister-exister) and [Mohamed Shaban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9678279/mohamed-shaban), and it solved it **partially**:

```swift
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)

    self.backgroundView = UIView()
    self.backgroundView?.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
```

However, the frames of gradientLayer just didn't meet my expectations, so I searched a bit more further, and found out, that it should be placed into another function. So I moved the gradientLayer to a class property, then overriden this function:

```swift
override func layoutSubviews() { self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds }
```

### Thank you for the helpful answers!

Answer (score 0):

i've tried it but i didn't get that UI bug. may you send me your  code and let me check if you want.
but generally i for a better practice i think, you should move cell UI code on it's cell class `AllCollectionViewCell`